# How to mock or get success with a context in a react-testing-library + jest test

Tags: jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, react-context, provider

I can't pass the tests with this context "ContextPosts". Gives me this error: "TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /Portfolio/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible".

This is the Inicio.test.js code (main page test):

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Inicio from './Inicio';
// import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { ContextPostsProvider } from './blog_articles/ContextBlog';

jest.mock('./blog_articles/ContextBlog')

beforeEach(()=>{
    render(
        <ContextPostsProvider>
            <Inicio />
        </ContextPostsProvider>
    )
});

test('Los parrafos estan en el documento?', async () => {
    // screen.debug();
    const texto = screen.getByText(/Portfolio/i);
    expect(texto).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This is the Inicio.jsx code (main page):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ContextPosts } from './blog_articles/ContextBlog';
import fotoPortadaPortfolio from '../../../src/img/portfolio/portada5.jpg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Inicio() {
    // obtener todos los posts con el hook useContext
    const { Posts } = useContext(ContextPosts);

    // obtener los nombres de todos los grupos, sin repetir
    const postGruposUnicos = [...new Set(Object.values(Posts).map(e => e.grupo))];
    // pasar el objeto Posts a array para manejar todos los posts
    const postsTodo = Object.entries(Posts);

    // ultimo post:
    // foto
    const indexUltimoPost = Object.entries(Posts).length - 1;
    const tituloUltimoPost = postsTodo[indexUltimoPost][1].titulo;
    const fotoPortadaUltimoPost = postsTodo[indexUltimoPost][1].portadaSrc;
    // links
    const idUltimoPost = Object.entries(Posts).filter(e => e[1].titulo === tituloUltimoPost)[0][0];
    const idPostRuta = (titulo) => Object.entries(Posts).filter(e => e[1].titulo === titulo)[0][0];
    
    // texto de muestra
    // const muestraTextoUltimoPost = postsTodo[indexUltimoPost][1].blablabla;


    return (
        <>
        <div className='inicio'>
            <header className='inicio__header'>
                <h1>
                    Bienvenid@ a ADP
                </h1>
                {/* Temporal pharagraph */}
                <p style={{backgroundColor: '#FFDC0011', color: '#FFDC00'}}>
                    ⚠️ Esta página está en actual desarrollo. El apartado de blogs está actualmente falto y pobre en cuanto contenido se refiere. Poco a poco iré añadiendo funcionalidades y contenido más variado, como puede ser, aparte de HTML, CSS, JavaScript, React, Git, etc. ⚠️
                </p>
                <p>
                    Aquí encontraras toda la información necesaria sobre desarrollo Frontend, tanto como si estás empezando en esto como si quieres reforzar ciertos conocimientos. Por lo tanto, sin importar el nivel que tengas, puede que te resulte interesante descubrir que te tengo preparado.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Todo el contenido que encontrarás en los posts del <Link to='/blog' style={{color: 'white', cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={()=>window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>Blog</Link> es contenido propio, sacado de mis <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>cientos de páginas</span> de apuntes que he ido escribiendo desde que empecé a estudiar programación en verano del 2021.
                </p>
                <p>
                    {/* Mi objetivo con éste proyecto de página es  */}
                </p>
            </header>
            <main className='inicio__main'>
                <section className='inicio__main__section'>
                    <article className='inicio__main__section__presentacion'>                        
                        <Link to={`/portfolio`} onClick={()=>window.scrollTo(0, 0)} className='inicio__main__section__presentacion__link'>
                            <article>
                                <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                                <h4>Álvaro de Prado</h4>
                                <img src={fotoPortadaPortfolio} alt='foto portada portfolio'></img>
                            </article>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to={`/blog/${idUltimoPost}`} onClick={()=>window.scrollTo(0, 0)} className='inicio__main__section__presentacion__link react-link'>
                            <article>
                                <h2>Último post</h2>
                                <h4>{tituloUltimoPost}</h4>
                                <img src={fotoPortadaUltimoPost} alt="foto de portada del último post"></img>
                            </article>
                        </Link>
                    </article>
                    <article className='inicio__main__section__rutas'>
                        <h2>Rutas de aprendizaje:</h2>
                        <p>Seguir en orden para aprender el lenguaje.</p>
                        {postGruposUnicos.map(grupo => {
                            return  <article>
                                <h4 key={grupo}>Ruta {grupo}</h4>
                                <ol> {/* ARREGLAR PROBLEMA DE KEY */}
                                    {postsTodo.map(e => e[1]).map(e => e.grupo === grupo ? <li key={e.titulo}><Link to={`/blog/${idPostRuta(e.titulo)}`} onClick={()=>window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>{e.titulo}</Link></li> : false)}
                                </ol>
                            </article>
                        })}
                    </article>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Inicio
```

This is the contextBlog.jsx (context):

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';


export const ContextPosts = createContext();

export const ContextPostsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [Posts] = useState({
        1: {
            grupo: 'CSS',
            titulo: 'Art.3',
            portadaSrc: '',
            contenido: (
                <div className='post'>
                    <span className='post__read-time'>Tiempo de lectura: x minutos</span>
                    <h1>Titulo obligatorio Art.3</h1>
                </div>
            )
        },
        2: {
            grupo: 'JavaScript',
            titulo: 'Art.4',
            portadaSrc: '',
            contenido: (
                <div className='post'>
                    <span className='post__read-time'>Tiempo de lectura: x minutos</span>
                    <h1>Titulo obligatorio Art.4</h1>
                </div>
            )
        },
    });

    return (
        <>
        <ContextPosts.Provider value={{ Posts }}>
            {children}
        </ContextPosts.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

export default ContextPostsProvider
```

I want to pass the test. I can pass i without context variables and things. Only with Inicio.jsx and his test I can pass it well.

Answer (score 0):

Try that code:

```js
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Inicio from "./Inicio";
// import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { ContextPostsProvider } from "./blog_articles/ContextBlog";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


test("Los parrafos estan en el documento?", async () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ContextPostsProvider>
        <Inicio />
      </ContextPostsProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  const texto = screen.getByText(/Portfolio/i);
  expect(texto).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

In your test you have several issues:

1. You did not use BrowserRouter but Inicio uses Link component inside
2. jest.mock('./blog_articles/ContextBlog')does not mock your ContextPostsProvider component and just returns a jest object
3. Forbidden usage of `render` within testing framework `beforeEach` setup (message from eslint)